# R shiny function to list input and output objects

Tags: r, shiny

Is there some way to quickly report the `input` and `output` objects in a previously-defined `fluidpage` object in shiny? Basically I'm looking for a way to quickly remind myself what I named different objects to speed up writing the server logic function. Obviously I can just scroll up in the script and look, but that can require a substantial amount of scrolling and searching to find what I want.

I don't see any relevant function in the Shiny [reference document](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/), and I guess I don't know what to google because I'm not finding anything...

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but in Shiny, inputs and outputs are named lists.  So you might for example use `renderText({names(input)})` or `renderText({names(output)})`

Comment: I'm looking for a way to see the names in R before running the app. The `fluidpage` (typically named `ui`) is a list, but it's an enormous list. I'm looking for a way to quickly go through that list, find objects with classes that hold `input` or `output` values and return the names of those objects.

Comment: renderText({names(output}) returns: impl ns